# Clojure: how to map over several regexes

Tags: regex, clojure

I would like to map over several regexes, but I get this error: `ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to java.util.regex.Pattern  clojure.core/re-matcher (core.clj:4634)`

I have a list of regexes:

```
(def ^:private regex-list
  [[#"expression1"]
  [#"expression2"]])
```

And I want to pass the regexes into this `map` function:

```
(defn replace-text [data body]
  (map #(re-find % body) regex-list))
```

If I `(ffirst hotel-regex)` I get #"expression1".  But there is a casting problem here.  I tried using `re-seq` instead of `re-find` but got the same result.  What is the right way to search for multiple regexes?

Comment: Remove the vectors around each regex in `regex-list` i.e. `(def regex-list [#"expression1" #"expression2"])`.

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: It works for me: `(map #(re-find % "123foobar") [#"\d+", #".oo"])` => `'("123" "foo")`

Comment: Right you are, and your suggestion to improve my syntax is valuable and an acceptable answer to me.  I was still getting the error because I stripped this piece out of a larger function and it was tripping over it later on where I hadn't used it in a map function.